# Page fields are inaccessible due to protection level

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

Okay, so I've got this website and I've got several arrays that are declared in the code behind. I'm trying to use them on the aspx page, but it tells me that they are inaccessible once I get down to a second level div element. See code:

Code behind:

```
string[] strFilePath = new string[5];
string[] strTitle = new string[5];
string[] strCity = new string[5];
string[] strCountry = new string[5];


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constr = 
  @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\TravelJoansDB.mdb;";
    string cmdstr = "SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Table2 ORDER BY TravelDate";
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con);

    con.Open();
    OleDbDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        reader.Read();
        strFilePath[i] = reader[2].ToString();
        strTitle[i] = reader[6].ToString();
        strCity[i] = reader[7].ToString();
        strCountry[i] = reader[8].ToString();
    }
}
```

And here's the ASP:

```
<a href="BlogPosts.aspx" id="iview"> 
    <!-- Slide 1 -->
    <div data-iview:image="placeImages/" + <%= strFilePath[0] %>>
    <!-- Caption 1 -->
        <div class="iview-caption" data-x="400" data-y="400" 
              data-transition="wipeRight"  data-speed="700">
           <h3><%= strTitle[0] %></h3>
           <%= strCity[0] %>, <%= strCountry[0] %>
       </div>
    </div>
```

So it tells me that `strTitle`, `strCity` and `strCountry` are inaccessible due to its protection level, but `strFilePath` is cool. I have a feeling that it is because of the class property of the div element. If that is so, is there a way to get around that? I tried using "this", but that didn't work either.

Comment: The CSS class of the div has no affect on the scope of variables in your code behind.

Comment: That's good to know. Any ideas on my problem?

Comment: You can't concatenate strings like this on an ASPX page `data-iview:image="placeImages/" + <%= strFilePath[0] %>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to make the variables protected so they can be seen in your page. They are private by default. The strFilePath isn't cool either, but is likely being ignored.

```
protected string[] strFilePath = new string[5];
protected string[] strTitle = new string[5];
protected string[] strCity = new string[5];
protected string[] strCountry = new string[5];
```

Comment: +1. When using the answer consider dropping `str` prefixes unless your local coding guidelines require usage of [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation).

Comment: Good deal. Thank you @dbugger. Now I have a new issue for which I'll make a separate question if I can't get it figure out soon enough. Thanks!